# how does this favicon.ico helps server bandwidth?

Tags: favicon

i was reading [programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716....](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site).. Question Answer in that there's a point sayin

`If you don’t have a /favicon.ico, this will result in a lot of 404s, draining your server’s bandwidth.`

i just dont know how this icon helps in saving server's bandwidth ? i know 404 is a `Not Found Error` message but what this `/favicon.ico` plays role here ?

please somebody explain me this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of possibilities. The first is that your `favicon.ico` file may be smaller than the 404 page, but that's probably not much of a difference.

However, if you have a massively complex custom 404 page that dynamically goes out to your database to get some information, there will be a hell of a difference in load compared to a static resource like the `favicon`.

The second is the possibility that a real `favicon` may be cached somewhere along the way, either in the browser displaying your page, or somewhere else not on your site.

This means that subsequent requests for it won't touch your server at all.

It's unlikely that a 404 received by the browser will be cached in the same way, so the browsers would be far more likely to try again next time, leading to more load on your servers.

---

In your comment, you question what the `favicon` is for so I'll cover that just in case: it's requested by browsers so that they can use it to (for example) provide an icon in the address bar, or on a bookmark, for your link.

That way, Google (for example) could have a `favicon` consisting of the stylised 'G', Wikipedia has their 'W', and so on. Even StackOverflow has their nifty little overflowing in-tray sitting to the left of my address bar right now.

See [the Wikipedia favicon entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) for more information than I want to cut-and-paste into this tiny text entry box :-)

Comment: thank you @paxdiablo but i didn't get coz m thinking that if you are requesting a non-existing page from my server, my server obviously will return 404 error page, so where and what job does favicon.ico doing ?

Comment: favicon = no 404 page. favicon < 404 page

Comment: @FosterZ, browsers will request the icon file. If you have one, it will be cached and your server won't be asked for it again until the cached version expires. It you give a 404, there's a good chance that _won't_ be cached so the browser will keep asking your server for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's because the 404 page has a larger size than the favicon.ico. At least most of the time it is...

Comment: hm but i guess 404 page is hardly 3kb, suppose you requesting a page that doesn't exists then any how 404 error page is shown, here in this scenario what does favicon's role ??

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have or want `/favicon.ico` on your site here's how to stop filling up your access_log and error_log with 404 hits. Add to this your apache conf or `.htaccess`:

```
## Send 204 "No Content" for /favicon.ico in the web root
Redirect 204 /favicon.ico
```